# remove redis from rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, redis

I was playing around with redis a bit, but decided against using it, and removed it from my app, and gem file.

When I upload my app to heroku, I get an error

```
2012-08-09T03:00:03+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actives
upport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': no such file t
o load -- redis (LoadError)
```

however, I can't find any `/app/vendor/bundle` path in my application (or on my machine), and `grep -r 'redis '` in the app directory didn't return any results.

How do I remove redis from my app, or why does Heroku think it is there.

I've gone through my initializers and there is no reference to redis anywhere.

Comment: Are you using resque? Check your gemfile.lock for "redis" it should show you if something else is requiring it.

Comment: @Schneems, I'm not using resque, and my gemfile.lock does not have any reference to "redis".  I assume if it did it would have been picked up by GREP. I grepped 'resque' and came up empty.

Comment: Strange, just add the redis gem back to your Gemfile. If you're not calling it in your application it won't affect much. If you deploy to a new heroku instance do you still get the error? What about if you uninstall redis from rvm and system, do you get the error when you run locally?

Comment: @schneems, turns out this was something that went wrong with the gemfile. I deleted the gemfile.lock, and recreated it, and that resolved the problem.

Comment: Glad you got it working!